# Form Validate with preg_match and send mail if all conditions are filled

Tags: php, validation, email

```
    //validate email

    if(empty($email)){
        $mailErr = "<div class='errors'>Email can not be empty.</div>";
    }else{
        if(!(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/", $email))){
            $mailErr = "<div class='errors'>Please input a valid email address.</div>";
        }
    }


    //validate message
    if (empty($message)) {
        $messageErr = "<div class='errors'>Message can not be empty.</div>";
    }
```

if both validation are true then send mail. please help me. How can I write this condition. I want if both conditions are fulfill then send the mail.

Comment: just use two separate if statements

Comment: You could use a simple flag – `$noErrors = true` in the beginning, and set it to false in your if conditions when an error has occurred. And before sending, you check the value of that flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Validate email
if (empty($email)) {
    $mailErr = "<div class='errors'>Email can not be empty.</div>";
} else if (!(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/", $email))){
    $mailErr = "<div class='errors'>Please input a valid email address.</div>";
} else {
    $valid_email = true;
}

// Validate message
if (empty($message)) {
    $messageErr = "<div class='errors'>Message can not be empty.</div>";
}else{
    $valid_message = true;
}

if ($valid_email && $valid_message) {
    // Send the email
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a short form to validate Email-Adresses using [FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) and you can just safe a variable, which contains an error status.

```
$error = false;

if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $mailErr = "<div class='errors'>Please input a valid email address.</div>";
   $error = true;
}

if (empty($message)) {
   $messageErr = "<div class='errors'>Message can not be empty.</div>";
   $error = true;
}

if(!$error) {
    //Send message here
}
```

You can also use a short form (but not checking both at the same time) without using a status variable:

```
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
   $mailErr = "<div class='errors'>Please input a valid email address.</div>";
} else if (empty($message)) {
   $messageErr = "<div class='errors'>Message can not be empty.</div>";
} else {
    //Send message here
}
```